# Why output is <seq> and not int in F#?

Tags: f#

This is my code:

```
 Csv.GetSample().Rows
 |> Seq.groupBy (fun row -> row.STATE,row.INCOME,row.CHILDREN)
 |> Seq.map (fun ((state,income,children),data) -> 
    let pctrepub = data|> Seq.map (fun row -> (100.0 - float row.otherparty)) 
    ((state,income,children),pctrepub))
 |> List.ofSeq
```

This is my ideal result:

```
   (("TX", "51522", "0"), 65.0);
   (("AL", "6481", "1"), 51.4);
   (("MO", "78921", "1"), 25.1);
   (("TN", "12000", "4"), 62.1);
   (("PA", "79850", "2"), 41.2);
   (("NY", "79215", "1"), 31.0);
   (("CA", "79045", "2"), 50.5);
```

This is what I am ending up with:

```
   (("TX", "51522", "0"), <seq>);
   (("AL", "6481", "1"), <seq>);
   (("MO", "78921", "1"), <seq>);
   (("TN", "12000", "4"), <seq>);
   (("PA", "79850", "2"), <seq>);
   (("NY", "79215", "1"), <seq>);
   (("CA", "79045", "2"), <seq>);
```

Why is the last row of values appearing as `<seq>` and how do I fix this?

Comment: Is `data` different from `Csv.GetSample().Rows`? you are mapping over both sequences, but you are extracting a full sequence for each row in the Csv sample. If `data` and `Csv.GetSample().Rows` are the same you can achieve what you want with one mapping.

Comment: Where is that `data` coming from? The code you're showing us shouldn't compile: when I try to reproduce your code I get a type error saying that `Rows` doesn't match a tuple of two elements. Could you show us a few lines of the input CSV that you're using?

Comment: I have updated the post. `data` is the rest of the data from CSV that I did not group by

Comment: you should try passing `row` instead of data

Comment: but that could be named anything. I could have named it trump. but good point it is more specific

Comment: @rmunn the CSV is exactly the same as what is above

Comment: Why are you using `groupBy` on a combination of state + income + children? Do you really expect to have more than one record in your data set with the *exact same* state, income, and children combination? And if you do, do you really want to conflate them? I feel like you're trying to do A, actually doing B, and getting confused because B doesn't act like A. What is the purpose you're trying to achieve with `Seq.groupBy` here?

Comment: the `groupby` doesn't make sense there. You can just do `Seq.map (fun row -> (row.STATE,row.INCOME,row.CHILDREN), 100.0 - float row.otherparty)`

Comment: also, tbh, if you are getting into tuples with more than three elements, maybe it's time to consider a  better data structure, like a record, or dictionary.

Comment: @s952163 - The `Row` data type produced by CsvProvider already acts like a record by having named properties, and that's enough for the data analysis that the OP is trying to do. That's good advice for the future, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mentioned elsewhere that you're a beginner at F# (started learning it eight days ago), so here's a quick guide to how to read the F# documentation that might help you answer some of these questions yourself. Let's look at the [documentation for the `Seq` module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.seq-module-%5Bfsharp%5D). It lists a lot of functions that can be called on sequences: `append`, `average`, `averageBy`, `filter`, `map`, `groupBy`... They all have different type signatures, and the type signature of each function is a clue to what it will do. Let's look at a few examples:

- `average` : **`seq<^T> -> ^T`** - Returns the average of the elements in 
  the sequence.
- `averageBy` : **`('T -> ^U) -> seq<'T> -> ^U`** - Returns the average of the results generated by applying the function to each element of the sequence.
- `map` : **`('T -> 'U) -> seq<'T> -> seq<'U>`** - Creates a new collection whose elements are the results of applying the given function to each of the elements of the collection.

First, `average`, since it's simplest. The `->` arrow in the type signure tells you that this is a function. The input is left of the arrow, and the output is right of the arrow. So that type signature means this function takes a `seq<^T>` and returns an item of type `^T`. The `^` or `'` characters in front of the type name `T` mean that it's a generic type, which will resolve to whatever type you actually have when you run the code: int, string, a tuple, whatever. So `T` is just a placeholder name for whatever type you actually have: if you have ints, this is a `seq<int> -> int` function. If you have strings, this is a `seq<string> -> string` function, and so on. (The `^` character in front of the type means that it will be resolved at compile-time, whereas a `'` character in front means it will be resolved at run-time. You won't need to worry about this distinction until you've had a lot more experience with F#, so for now, just treat either one of these as a flag that means "This is a generic type"). So the type signature of the `average` function tells you that it takes a *sequence of values* and returns *a single value*.

Now, `averageBy`. This is more complicated. First, there are more arrows here. This is related to a concept called [currying](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/), which is explained very well at the link so I won't dive into it. At the beginner level, you should think of whatever comes after the *final* arrow as being the output of the function, and all the rest of the types as being the inputs of the function (which will be separated by arrows). In other words, a type signature like `int -> char -> string` should be read as "this is a function that takes two inputs, an `int` first and a `char` second, and returns a `string`."

But do you see the parentheses around the `('T -> ^U)` bit in the `averageBy` type signature? Those parentheses mean just what they mean in math: read this part in isolation. So the first parameter of `averageBy` is something of type `('T -> ^U)`. The second parameter of `averageBy` is of type `seq<'T>`, and the output is of type `^U`. Now if you look at the type signature `('T -> ^U)`, it has an arrow in it, so it's a function. Specifically, it's a function that takes a thing of generic type `T` and returns a thing of generic type `U`. (As I said earlier, don't worry about the `'` vs. `^` distinction right now). The second parameter is a sequence of items of type `T`, and the output is of type `U`. That type signature, plus the name, gives you a clue as to how the function works: it will look through the sequence of things of type `T`, and for each one, it will call the function to convert that `T` thing into a thing of type `U`. Then it returns a single `U` value as the output: from the name, you can conclude that the single value it returns will be the average of all the `U` values produced by the `'T -> ^U` function.

So the type signature `('T -> ^U) -> seq<'T> -> ^U` means that the first argument is a function that takes a `T` and returns a `U`, the second argument is a sequence of items of type `T`, and the function returns a single item of type `U`.

Finally, let's look at `map`. Its type signature looks rather similar to `averageBy`: the first parameter is again a function that takes a `T` and converts it to a `U`. The second parameter is again a sequence of `T` items. But this time, instead of a single value, the result of `map` will be a *sequence* of `U` values.

And so, by looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/collections.seq-module-%5Bfsharp%5D), we can see that if you don't want a sequence as output, `Seq.map` is the wrong thing to call. There's a bewildering list of functions in the `Seq` module, so you might feel a bit overwhelmed. But carefully looking at the type signatures, and understanding what each one means, is a big help in figuring out which one will do what you want with your data. And reading through https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/list-module-functions/ will be a big help to you too: F# carefully treats the `List`, `Seq` and `Array` modules as *extremely similar to each other*, including having almost all the same functions. So if you know what `List.averageBy` does, you will also know what `Seq.averageBy` and `Array.averageBy` do as well: the only difference will be in what type of collection they take as input. So even though that page talks about lists, its advice also applies to Seq as well.

Someone has already answered your question in the comments (just do `Seq.map (fun row -> (row.STATE,row.INCOME,row.CHILDREN), 100.0 - float row.otherparty)` and you should get the result you want), so I won't go into more details there. Hopefully the time I spent to write this will be useful to you in helping you understand things in more depth, so that you can answer your own questions in the future and won't have to be quite as reliant on asking on Stack Overflow (and then waiting, sometimes hours, for the answers).

Answer (score 2):

The last element of the tuple is `pctrepub`, which is the result of a `Seq.map` call, and `Seq.map` returns a sequence, not a number. So it's absolutely no surprise that the last element of the tuple is a sequence.

As to how to fix this, there is not enough information: I see that you want to get number instead of sequences, but you're not saying where the numbers should come from, so I can't help you there.